# Is there a way to access the Xpath selector that Watir uses for selenium?

Tags: css, ruby, xpath, watir

I'm familiar with using the various different approaches to selecting elements in Watir. Instead, I want to do the opposite: I have an element which I have already enumerated, and I want to generate a unique reference for it.

I can obviously use the Watir hash reference to access the element inside the app, but I also want something that is generic, like an Xpath selector, which makes sense to wetware outside the app.

Is there a method in watir to acces the xpath directly?

Comment: Unique reference in your memory or in HTML?

Comment: Watir gives me a unique reference I can use in the code, I'm looking for the laziest way to create a unique CSS selector I can use outside the code.

Comment: Ah I get it. I have an idea. Let us create a new attribute named `element_id` for every element and then you could use that to create your css, what do you say?

Comment: Maybe. So, from a browser, if you inspect an element using the developer tools, you can see the CSS selector for the element. This you can use in Watir for referencing an element. That bit is fine. I want to work the other way. I enumerate a document in Watir, and I have an element I can query: what I am looking for is the easiest way to produce a CSS selector for it, the same as the browser does.

Comment: That's what I am saying. We enumerate all the elements and fix id for each element and then from outside, you could that element id to refer that element, what do you say?

Comment: Generating a CSS selector on the fly isn't that difficult (its mostly just building a path backwards using the element's parents, then testing it for uniqueness), the question was more about whether there is already an easy way to do this in Watir, or do I need to do it myself.

Comment: Watir doesn't provide a method for this. You'd have to create one yourself.

Comment: I was suspecting as much: thanks for the confirmation. I think I'll solve the problem by injecting a script to create a unique CSS selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method isn't exposed (as confirmed by Justin Ko in the comments).